# SQLite How to Include Records Where NULL in Objective C?

Tags: sqlite

I’m attempting to count records that match specific criteria, including one field being null, but including the null clause results in no records being found.

If I output the contents of the field, it comes back as “(null)”. I’ve tried IS NULL and ISNULL, both of which appear that they should work when looking at other sources, but they both fail for me.

```sql
SELECT calls.contact_number, calls.contact_name, COUNT(notes.id) AS note_count
FROM calls LEFT JOIN notes on calls.id = notes.call_id 
WHERE calls.contact_number = "123" AND notes.group_id ISNULL
GROUP BY calls.contact_number
```

This returns no records, whereas I’m expecting it to return one.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition in the ON clause:

```
SELECT calls.contact_number, calls.contact_name, COUNT(notes.id) AS note_count
FROM calls LEFT JOIN notes 
ON calls.id = notes.call_id AND notes.group_id IS NULL 
WHERE calls.contact_number = "123" 
GROUP BY calls.contact_number, calls.contact_name
```

Comment: I tried this, and still had no joy. I tried changing it to IS NOT NULL, and it returned a result. Outputting the value from the result set to a string gives “(null)”.

Comment: What do you need NULLS or NOT NULLs?

Comment: I need NULLS, but it seems to think it’s NOT NULLS. Would this be from putting the query in to a NSString before passing that in using FMDatabase?

Comment: *I need NULLS, but it seems to think it’s NOT NULLS* this does not make sense. Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: If I include notes.group_id in the SELECT statement, the value that’s being returned is “(null)”.

Answer (score 0):

After grabbing a copy of the database, the notes.group_id field was determined to be an integer type, and the record in question actually contained a 0.

The successful query ended up being

```sql
SELECT calls.contact_number, calls.contact_name, COUNT(notes.id) as note_count
FROM calls LEFT JOIN notes
ON calls.id = notes.call_id
WHERE calls.contact_number = “123” AND (notes.group_id IS NULL OR notes.group_id = 0)
GROUP BY calls.contact_number
```

Not sure why the NSLog output of the returned value for group_id was ‘(null)’, some weird conversion?